# logging long subprocess sdtout

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I am struggling with an issue certainly due my lack of understanding on the modules.
I have to start chained long analysis scripts which are generating a huge amount of output both on stdout and stderror. I need to log the ouput of subprocess call with the logging module. The following code is working as long as the output is not too big, but once it is it just ends with a truncated log file.

```
import logging, subprocess

def popen_log(commandL, logFile):
    p = subprocess.Popen(commandL, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
    #create logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create file handler which logs even debug messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler(logFile)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info(stdout)
    logger.error(stderr)
    logger.removeHandler(fh)

popen_log(['script1.py', '-i', inputFolder], 'test.log')
```

It certainly has something to do with the streaming of the stdout and stderror to the log file or with the buffering but I just cannot figure out how to do so. Any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) instead. This will let you choose the maximum size of each log file. It automatically begins logging in a new file whenever this limit is reached.

Comment: Thanks, that could do, I ideally wished to keep everything in a single file. I will have a try.